# How to display the information contained in a related model's field in Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In my application I have the following two models:

```
class CondRecordHdr(models.Model):
    cond_prices_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Cond ID')
    cond_type = models.ForeignKey(AlliedPriceCondType, ...
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, ...

class Dependency(models.Model):
    cond_dependency = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...
    prc_cond_hdr = models.ForeignKey(CondRecordHdr, ...
    prc_select_obj = models.CharField(max_length=15, ...
```

I am placing the objects of the first model in the listview with:

```
class CondRecListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'obj_context'
    model = CondRecordHdr 
    template_name = ...

    def get_queryset(self):
       return CondRecordHdr.objects.order_by(...
```

Then I am using the context object to display the data in a tabular form in the template.

I am displaying the data like this:

| Cond Type | Material | Dependency (Note1) | Xyz | More fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCHG | Mouse | blank | abc1 |  |
| IPRO | Keyboard |  | abc2 |  |

**Note 1**: In this column I want to display the value of **field** `prc_select_obj` **model** `Dependency`, where I have no data being displayed currently (`blank`).

**How do I display** the information contained in model `Dependency` in the same template (in column shown above `Note1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access to the related model **Dependency** from **CondRecordHdr** in a template by the name set in the field with param `related_name`:

```
prc_cond_hdr = models.ForeignKey(CondRecordHdr, related_name="dependencies",...)

# And in the template
{% for obj in obj_context %}
{% for dep in obj.dependencies.all %}
{{dep.prc_select_obj}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Without **related_name** set in the field, the default related_name is set to  **MODENAME_set**, in your case: `{% for dep in obj.dependency_set.all %}`

More detail in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the same way to do it in my template but getting multiple hits (values). Need to filter it to display **only associated** values. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show your updated code please ? it is a one to many relations, so it is normal to have multiple values

Comment: I have been able to resolve it. What I did was: Updated the context object by overriding `get_context_data` (passing child model **Dependency** objects) and  then in the template using filter on field `prc_cond_hdr == cond_prices_id`, I have been able to get the job done. Thanks.